# Cannot Load Texture/Bitmap From GLSurfaceView.Renderer

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, bitmap

I am trying to load a bitmap image into my GLSurfaceView but I am not seeing anything rendered. Not sure why! I tried a lot but haven't got any clue. I know that OnDrawFrame method is getting called (checked) but I don't see any affect on my GLSurfaceView. When I set background for the view, I can see background color. Please help.

```
class ClearRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
     int[] textureIds = null;
    public ClearRenderer()
    {

    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        if(textureIds == null) {
            textureIds = new int[1];
            gl.glGenTextures( 1, textureIds, 0 );
        }

    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
    //gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl) {

    Bitmap solidColorBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Config.ARGB_8888);
    solidColorBitmap.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);


    gl.glActiveTexture(textureIds[0]);

    gl.glBindTexture( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIds[0] );

    // Create Nearest Filtered Texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);


    // Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, solidColorBitmap, 2 );
    }
}

class MainMonitor extends GLSurfaceView {

    ClearRenderer render = new ClearRenderer();

    public MainMonitor(Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.setRenderer(render);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }
}
```

This is how I am adding the GLSurfaceView from my activity. (topLayout has other layout). I know problemView is on on top - when I set backgroud color, I can see the cyan color patch of 1000x1000.

```
problemView = new MainMonitor(this);
((GLSurfaceView) problemView ).requestRender();

problemView .setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(1000, 1000,1));
//problemView .setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

topLayout.addView(problemView);

setContentView(topLayout);
```

Comment: When we draw bitmap after drawing the square it is showing up (As in http://obviam.net/index.php/texture-mapping-opengl-android-displaying-images-using-opengl-and-squares/). I'll look into the details of it and let you know.